# Function that returns the list index of a substring

Tags: python, list, substring

I am struggling trying to create a function which searches a list to see if any of the strings contained within it are `substrings` of any of the other strings within the same list. If a `substring` is found it should return the `index` number and if none are found it should return `False`

For example.

```
lst1 = ["red", "yellow", "green", "yellowhammer"]
lst2 = ["red", "yellow", "green"]
```

In this example, `lst1` would return a value of 1 as `yellow` is a `substring` of `yellowhammer` and `lst2` would return a value of `False` as there are no `substrings`.

I have tried the following

```
templst = lst1
for i in templst:
    if i in lst1:
       return i
    else:
        return False
```

However this does not work because it always finds itself so even if there are no `substrings` it returns a value even if it should return `False`.

Comment: `i` is an item in this case, not an index. Try `for i, item in enumerate(a_list)` instead, which is considered to be the right way to iterate over the index and the items of a list in Python.

Comment: In your code, you are missing closing quotation marks around the string `"yellow"`

Comment: I think you want to actually return more than one index. If you only return `1` you will not know which other string `1` is a sub-string of. If you return `(1, 3)`, then you will know that string `1` is a substring of string `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should accomplish what you need. The details of how this is accomplished are commented within.

```
# Lists that OP provided
lst1 = ["red", "yellow", "green", "yellowhammer"]
lst2 = ["red", "yellow", "green"]

# Function that checks the list
def checkList(myList):
        # Create a variable to hold the concatenated string
        total = ""

        # Build the concatenated string
        for item in myList:
                total += item

        # Loop through the list again
        for i, item in enumerate(myList):
                # Count the amount of times each item appears in the concatenation
                curr = total.count(item)
                # If its more than one, since it will always appear once
                if(curr > 1):
                        # Return its index
                        return i
        # Otherwise, return False
        return False
# Test the two test samples
list_1_ans = checkList(lst1)
list_2_ans = checkList(lst2)

# Print out results
print("First Test Answer: {} | Second Test Answer: {}".format(list_1_ans, list_2_ans))
```

Yields:

```
First Test Answer: 1 | Second Test Answer: False
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return the output you need

```
def check_subs(lst1):
    answer = {1 if x in y and x !=y else 0 for x in lst1 for y in lst1}
    if sum(answer)>0:
        return answer
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: This fails OP's test cases by printing `0` for `lst2` instead of `False`

Answer (score 0):

First, to create a function, you want to use the `def` keyword.  This is a function that takes a list of strings as its input and returns either a `bool` or an `int`, so with type hints it'll look like:

```
from typing import List, Union

def index_of_substring(strings: List[str]) -> Union[bool, int]:
    """The first index whose item is a substring of a different 
    item in the same list, or False if no such item exists."""
    # implement me
    pass
```

Now we need to implement the body of the function in terms of its `strings` argument.  Since we want to return the index within the list, it makes sense to iterate over the `range` of list indices:

```
    for i in range(len(strings)):
```

Each `i` in this loop is an index (e.g. in your `list1` it'll be a number from 0 to 3).  Now we want to ask the question "is the item at this index a substring of `any` other item other than itself?"

To answer that question, we want to ask about other indexes in the list that we can compare to our current index `i`; we'll call those other indexes `j`:

```
for j in range(len(strings))
```

and the conditions we want to satisfy relative to `i` are:

```
strings[i] in strings[j] and i != j
```

We can put this all together in a *list comprehension* that will give us a list which tells us which items in the range satisfy that `and` condition:

```
[strings[i] in strings[j] and i != j for j in range(len(strings))]
```

and we want to know if `any` of those items are `True`:

```
any([strings[i] in strings[j] and i != j for j in range(len(strings))])
```

If they are, we want to return `i`.  We want to repeat this check for each `i`, and if *none* of them are true, we want to return `False`.  The complete function looks like:

```
def index_of_substring(strings: List[str]) -> Union[bool, int]:
    for i in range(len(strings)):
        if any([strings[i] in strings[j] and i != j for j in range(len(strings))]):
            return i
    return False
```

and we can call it like this:

```
print(index_of_substring(lst1))
print(index_of_substring(lst2))
```

which prints:

```
1
False
```